# How do i implement supertype/subtype in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

I have an supertype entity called **Game** and two subtype called **competitve** and **friendly**. How do I impement that in mysql?

For example, would i just use primary key of **Game** as FK in the two subtypes? Because both subtypes have common attribute inherited from supertype **Game**, how would I show the inheritance of the common attribute?

Comment: so Game is the parent table and friendly and competitive are the child tables?

Comment: Yeah the game table is the parent and competitive and friendly are its child

Comment: if that is the case you should go for foreign key relationship

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, i might not have worded it properly(english not first language) say for example i have a attribute called 'location' in the game table will the foreign key relation suffice in the subtype inherting the 'location' attribute or do i need to create another field called location in 'friendly' table?